# SQL Top parent record in hierarchy

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I have a table with structure:

CompanyID, CompanyName, LinkedCompanyID

so that multiple companies can be linked in a hierarchy

e.g.

```
CompanyID, CompanyName, LinkedCompanyID
1          Company A,   NULL
2          Company B,   1
3          Company C,   2
4          Company D,   2
5          Company E,   4
6          Company F,   3
7          Company G,   NULL
```

I would like a query to return the top level parent of each company

i.e.

```
CompanyID, CompanyName, ToplevelParentID
1          Company A,   NULL (or 1 I don't mind)
2          Company B,   1
3          Company C,   1
4          Company D,   1
5          Company E,   1
6          Company F,   1
7          Company G,   NULL (or 7 I don't mind)
```

I've taken a look at using a recusive CTE expression but all the examples I can find return the hierarchial list from the parent down rather than the top most parent.

Can anybody please provide any pointers or a sample query

Comment: Strong suggestion: Add a field tracking the "top container". I do that in similar scenarios (and some intetim knwdes are their own containers - for example CMS: folter strucure to document, which is a container, then structure within the document. This makes a lot easier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can still be achieved with a recursive CTE:

```
CREATE TABLE #Test (CompanyID INT, CompanyName VARCHAR(20), LinkedCompanyID INT)
INSERT INTO #Test
SELECT  1, 'Company A',   NULL UNION
SELECT  2, 'Company B',   1 UNION
SELECT  3, 'Company C',   2 UNION
SELECT  4, 'Company D',   2 UNION
SELECT  5, 'Company E',   4 UNION
SELECT  6, 'Company F',   3 UNION
SELECT  7, 'Company G',   NULL

;WITH CTE AS
(   SELECT  *, 0 [Level]
    FROM    #Test
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  CTE.CompanyID, CTE.CompanyName, #Test.LinkedCompanyID, Level + 1
    FROM    CTE
            INNER JOIN #Test
                ON CTE.LinkedCompanyID = #Test.CompanyID
    WHERE   #Test.LinkedCompanyID IS NOT NULL
)

SELECT  c.CompanyID, c.CompanyName, c.LinkedCompanyID
FROM    (   SELECT  *, MAX([Level]) OVER (PARTITION BY CompanyName) [MaxLevel]
            FROM    CTE
        ) c
WHERE   MaxLevel = Level

DROP TABLE #Test
```

Comment: That's perfect.  So I need to use a CROSS APPLY as well as a CTE.  I understand the CTE part of it, would you mind explaining what the cross apply does

Comment: The final query just gets the row inserted by the last recursion of the CTE. There is more than one way this could be achieved (INNER JOIN, EXISTS) but I think in this scenario using the OVER function is the most efficient way to do it. If you SELECT * FROM CTE instead you should get a better picture of the how the final query limiting the output to the top level company. The subquery C is only used because Windowed functions can’t appear in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
Select * , (select CompanyName from  Company C_aux where C_Main.LinkedCompanyID = C_aux.CompanyID) as ToplevelParentID
from Company C_Main
```

Comment: Thanks but that only returns the closest parent and not the top level parent